# Java reflection - Invoke method with int[][] argument

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, reflection

I have this method defined within MatrixOperation class:

```
private static int getLargestSubMatrixSize(int[][] inputMatrix, int[][] arrResult){}
```

I need to invoke this method using reflection

I tried this approach, but I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodException`:

```
Method method = MatrixOperations.class.getMethod("getLargestSubMatrixSize", int[][].class, int[][].class);
method.setAccessible(true);
int maxCount = (int) method.invoke(null, inputMatrix, resultMatrix);
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: `MatrixOperations.class.getDeclaredMethod`...? The docs of `getMethod` explicitly state *Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is `private` and `getMethod` only returns public methods:

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

What you want to use instead is `getDeclaredMethod`:

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified declared method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

Comment: That's correct, thanks!
I was doubting `int[][].class` to be the real culprit, didn't pay attention to the Method class API.